# Returning HTML to Shortcode Block

Tags: shortcode, html

I have spent way too much time trying to clean this up.

I am simply attempting to return some HTML from a shortcode, into a shortcode block within the content editor.

```
$next_friday = new DateTime();
$next_friday->modify('next friday');
$final_date = $next_friday->format('l, F j, Y');
    
$reponse_formatted = "<h3 class='has-text-align-left'>$final_date</h3>";
$reponse_formatted .= "<p>Pre-sale for <u>Next Friday</u> Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm</p>";

return $response_formatted;
```

Pretty straightforward ... but the end results is this HTML on the front end:

```
<h3 class="has-text-align-left">Friday, October 15, 2021</h3>
<p>
    "Pre-sale for "
     <u>Next Friday</u>
    " Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm"
</p>
```

What is going on with this shortcode block? I just need it to render normally, like:

```
<h3 class="has-text-align-left">Friday, October 15, 2021</h3>
<p>Pre-sale for <u>Next Friday</u> Will Start on Tuesday at 5pm</p>
```

Comment: What’s the problem? Are the quotes appearing?

Comment: The problem is that it ends up displaying as I showed above: quotes, extra spaces, return lines...

Comment: As visible to end users? Or in the HTML? If you're looking at the HTML in dev tools, the quotes and line breaks are perfectly normal.